# REST APIs using wrong verb for a request

Tags: rest

I read that `PUT` is used for creating or updating a resource while `POST` is used for creating a resource.

What would happen if I used `POST` for updating a resource.

In general why what would happen if i use the wrong verb for wrong request. For example, what would happen if i use `GET` request to create a new entry in my back end database?

Comment: Technically speaking you can code a RESTful api to do whatever it is you want it to, but the reason there are best practices and guidelines is to provide a standardisation. Therefore, those that consume an API understand what is required as it is semantically correct. Also going against the standard REST principals would be a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

> What would happen if I used POST for updating a resource.

If you are the developer then nothing will happen except cofusing the API users and not being in the RESTful best practices.

You can refer to [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest?rq=1) in order to understand better the difference between the 2 and why it's better to stick with the guidelines.

> For example, what would happen if i use GET request to create a new entry in my back end database?

Same answer as above, not in the RESTful spirit neither best practices. But I think that are misunderstanding something in the HTTP protocol though:

**GET :** is better suited to ask for something.

**POST:** is better suited to ask for something while providing some information (It goes like this : Hey server! here are some data, and make me some data based on them. This is why it's generally used for updating, ***because it has a payload***, so basically POST = GET + Payload).

Asking if you can use GET to create a new update in a database is kind of non-sense, since GET is generally used just to *ask* for data. GET does have limited payload information embeded directly in the URL, so you can't separate well the URL from the Payload.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about `semantics`.

As per [REST # 9 Method Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html),

> POST is designed to [..]

So no one can *enforce* you to apply those rules, even though it was *designed* to be used in a way (I would say a proper one).

Comment: Please, use the newer version specified in RFC 7230-7237 [(in specific 7231)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3) rather then the obsolete RFC 2616.

Comment: @RomanVottner I was trying to make my point, the version is not really relevant in this context.